# What is the size limit of a list in Michelson

Tags: michelson

Can lists be used to store large amounts of data like big maps ?

The doc (https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html?highlight=michelson%20types#core-data-types-and-notations) doesn't talk about the size limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The practical limit to the size of a list in Michelson is the amount of gas it will cost to call the contract.

Every time a contract is called it is parsed, which means the contract code and entire storage are read out of the Tezos database. You pay gas according to the binary size of the data read.  Except for any big maps which do not have their contents parsed, and are instead only accessed by key within your code.

The gas limit per operation is 800,000 but the current Carthage proposal intends to raise it by 30% to 1,040,000. The limit to the size of your list depends on how many bytes it contains because part of the gas calculation is the parsing of all the data on every call.

The best way to know how much gas it will cost to call your contract is to test it by running simulations with the --dry-run param